# Access specific JSON value from JSON data - *error unexpected token $ at...*

Tags: javascript, json, get

```
{"user" : $payload.user,"Class" : "Division-II","Branch" : "div_branch-1"}
```

I have the above json data, when I'm trying to access this via GET request and display on HTML page, I'm able to display when using `respone => response.text()`, but I'm getting unexpected token `$` at 10 when I'm using `response => response.json()`.

```
 fetch('http://localhost:3000/features,{
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      var user = data[user];
})
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: The received JSON is invalid. How are you creating the data?

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` is a lie. You aren't posting JSON to the server at all.

Comment: "I have the above json data" — As the error message says, that isn't valid JSON. You need to fix that.

Comment: It's actually an existing data.

Comment: @HarshatejM — Pre-existing or not, it's still not JSON

Comment: You've to search for the error source from your server-side code. It looks like you've an unserialized reference (`$payload.user`) in `{"user" : $payload.user, ...}`, you've to find the line which creates that value from your code in the server. Instead of manually building JSON, you should use the methods of the used language to convert some data to JSON. Also, as Quentin said, you're not passing any data to your server with that `fetch` call.

Comment: In general, it's not useful to start arguing when two users tell you what's wrong with your code. Instead, add the asked information to your post, you'll have much better chances to get a good answer.

Comment: Sorry if it felt like I was arguing, but actually * It's actually an existing data* was the answer to your question -> *How are you creating the data?*  :|
And, Thank you @Teemu and Quentin for the solution suggestions!

Comment: Mmm ... I don't feel that comment answers my question. If you'd added your server-side code which creates the data, then the question would have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that this object:

```js
$payload = {user: 'something'};
alert(JSON.stringify({"user" : $payload.user,"Class" : "Division-II","Branch" : "div_branch-1"}));
```

can only be evaluated if `$payload` is defined. If I define `$payload`, see the snippet above, then the code can be evaluated properly. So, your server-side assumed that `$payload` was properly initialized, but it was not.